# Jquery append some context to specific iframe page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want append some context to iframe page

**all  the js codes are in parent page & parent page and iframe page are in same domain**

selector:

```
$('#iframe_id').contents().find('#target_element_id').append(context);
```

some info :

```
console.log($('#iframe_id').contents().find('#target_element_id'))
```

we get :

```
[prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "#target_element_id"]
```

but it doestn`t effect , why ?

> *I think in this action  we just load all the iframe code and run it in the parent page , I can  change anything just like I do it in
>   parent page*

is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       setTimeout(function () {
           $('#iframe1').contents().find('#target_element_id').append("text_2_appended");
       }, 50);
        });


<body>

<iframe src="test.html" id="iframe1">       

  </iframe>
```

Comment: Please do not post code only answers. Those are unlikely to help future visitors. Consider adding an explaination to this answer of yours.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.